# AspireOne D255E RAM Compatibility

Tags: memory

The Aspire-One D255E RAM specs sold by crucial.com includes:

http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/aspire-one-d255e-%28intel-atom-n455%29-ddr3/CT5629593

```
DDR3 PC3-12800 • CL=11 • Unbuffered • NON-ECC • DDR3-1600 • 1.35V •
```

I have [this Samsung 2GB SO-DIMM](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00DUG7GTE) on-hand and was wondering can I disqualify from use in the Aspire-One:

```
Manufacturer    Samsung
Manufacturer Part #    M471B5773CHS-CH9
Memory Type    SODIMM
Capacity    2GB
Pins    204 Pin
Bus Type    PC-10600
Error Correction    Non-ECC
Cycle Time    1.5ns
Cas    CL9
Data Transfer Rate    1333Mhz
Memory Clock    166Mhz
Rank    Rank 1
Voltage    1.5
```

As I understand it: having a lower CLX (CL9) is better than having a higher number (CL11).  Both seem to have 204 pins, but that is no guarantee of compatibility (though have different numbers of pins does confer incompatibility).      The bus types are different: PC10600 vs PC12800

## [Update: RAM specs from CNET review](https://www.cnet.com/products/acer-aspire-one-d255e-13639-10-1-atom-n455-1-gb-ram-250-gb-hdd/specs/)

[image]

## Photo of Installed Module for comparison with Samsung Module

Upper module is Kingston (Acer Issued)
Lower module is Samsung
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The Acer Aspire-One D255E model has some hardware difficulty in getting SPD data and therefore likely can't intelligently configure RAM. At least the CPUinfo shows SPD field as blanks. [According to this blog](http://www.laptop-forums.com/threads/aspire-one-d255e-supporting-4gb-ram-is-this-right.22459/), the D255E works only with 1333MHz memory, and fails with slower SODIMMS.

I am typing this on the D255E model, and I did upgrade the original 1GB memory to a 2GB SODIMM. I can't remember which one I did use, need to open the netbook up. I can tell that graphics performance has doubled from "experience index "1" to index "2.4" under Win7, which is quite more enjoyable.

EDIT: I just checked my successful memory upgrade. The blog info appears to be not true: my memory is Hynix 2GB 1Rx8 PC3-10600S-9-10-B1, and it works just fine.

Comment: Excellent post with useful facts.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Upon opening the machine and comparing the Samsung module with the OEM, it is physically impossible to install the Samsung module because of the two modules are physically notched \ keyed differently to prevent an improper install

Comment: Per Intel ark database, the Atom N455 processor (inside the D255E netbook) can be configured to support both DDR2 and DDR3 memory types. It is possible that there were several modifications of the AspireOne netbook. Your model looks like a DDR2 model.

Comment: @AliChen: Is it possible to ascertain from the photos of the RAM if they are DDR2 or DDR3?

Comment: Yes, the upper image is DDR2, the second one is DDR3

Comment: Thanks AliChen: ordered: https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B001342KM8/   based on http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/Acer/aspire-one-d255e-(intel-atom-n450)-ddr2